# Add +1 incremental based in a value of a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm having a hard time trying to code a algorithm that add +1 to a "Card Number" based in the amount of the column "Card Amount".

[An Exemple of what i need]

[image: 1]

I'll post what i've already tried, and the error that is happening.

The ValueError thats is happening is the

> "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

```
cod_1 = pd.Series({'Card Number':'1000','Card Amount': 4})
cod_2 = pd.Series({'Card Number':'2000','Card Amount': 5})
cod_3 = pd.Series({'Card Number':'3000','Card Amount': 3})

df = pd.DataFrame([cod_1, cod_2, cod_3])
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Card Amount'])]

for amt in df['Card Amount'].unique():
    number = 0
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        if df.loc[index,'Card Amount'] == amt:
            df.loc[index,'Card Number'] = df.loc[index,'Card Number'] + number
            number += 1
```

[image: Image - ValueError]

Comment: replace if  condition with `row['Card Amount'] == amt:` , but if you explain what you are trying to do , you can do it without any loop

Comment: I posted a image of what i need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright IIUC,you just need one line of code :

```
df['Card Number'] = df['Card Number'].astype(int) + df.groupby('Card Number').cumcount()
```

output :

```
    Card Number  Card Amount
0          1000            4
1          1001            4
2          1002            4
3          1003            4
4          2000            5
5          2001            5
6          2002            5
7          2003            5
8          2004            5
9          3000            3
10         3001            3
11         3002            3
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have repeated indexes in your df:

```
  Card Number  Card Amount
0        1000            4
0        1000            4
0        1000            4
0        1000            4
1        2000            5
1        2000            5
1        2000            5
1        2000            5
1        2000            5
2        3000            3
2        3000            3
2        3000            3
```

So when you call `df.loc[index,'Card Amount']`, this returns all the rows with an 0 index:

```
0    4
0    4
0    4
0    4
Name: Card Amount, dtype: int64
```

This is a series, so comparing it against the integer `amt` causes your error. I would suggest building your dataframe without using `index.repeat`, or using `df.reset_index()` before running.

You will then get an issue with the line after the if statement, as your Card Number column is stored as strings and the number variable is int. You can convert the card number to an integer to add the number to it:

```
df.loc[index,'Card Number'] = int(df.loc[index,'Card Number']) + number
```